# Is the Instagram Search distance a Radius or a Diameter?

Tags: instagram

Is the Distance parameter on the Instagram Search API specifying a radius from the given point, or a diameter passing through that point?

I'm asking because it seems that even though I know there's an image in a particular place, at a particular time, the API doesn't return that image when I query for it at the exact spot & time that it was taken.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What are the parameters you are using to search? And what image are you expecting to see that is not being returned? That might help in debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance parameter is for the radius around the point defined by the lat/lng.

The image will not be returned if the user's account is private. That might be why you are not seeing it in your results.

Comment: So you think it's a radius? That makes sense, but the documentation doesn't actually state that, and tests give mixed results. The image I'm trying to fetch is not private--I can get it through the API, but only by direct lookup, not via geo search. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you get it via the API, does the media object contain a lat and lng?

Comment: Yes it does contain those parameters.

Comment: It's also not clear when it comes to units. The "documentation" led me to believe I had to put in "500m" or "2km" but in reality it seems to always be in meters and I may not include any units -- just the number, for any results to be returned.

Comment: Correct, the distance parameter is entered in meters, with no unit of measurement included. So distance=1000 would be a 1kilometer radius.